# How to fix this warning "Very long vector path (7985 characters), which is bad for performance" in xml file of android kotlin

Tags: xml, performance, path, warnings, long-integer

How to fix this warning --- "Very long vector path (7985 characters), which is bad for performance. Considering reducing precision, removing minor details or rasterizing vector." in the layout resource file.

```
<vector android:height="200dp" android:viewportHeight="500"
<path android:fillColor="#e0e0e0" android:pathData="M304,247.48c0.43,-0.67 -1.2,-2.29 -1.21,-3s0.14,-0.3 0.36,-1.46 -1.26,-0.61 -2,-1.72 0.22,-0.64 -0.3,-1.39 -2.34,-0.15 -2.82,-0.53 0,-1.2 -1.08,-1.88 -2.48,0.86 -3.4,0.53 -0.91,-1.06 -1.74,-0.74 -1.65,1.57 -3.38,1.64 -2.34,0.41 -2.34,1.28 -0.07,1.48 -1.67,2.62 -0.89,2.65 -0.13,3.86 -0.83,1.65 -1.06,2.55 1.89,2 2,2.89 -1,2.08 0.82,3.43 1.81,0 2.64,0.75 2.86,2.34 3.59,2a4.68,4.68 0,0 1,2.35 -0.51c0.53,0.15 2.83,0.06 3,-1.06s1.48,-1.57 2.3,-1.47 0.9,-2.13 1.07,-2.81 1.34,-0.38 2.05,-1.3 -0.33,-1.79 -0.23,-2.23S303.52,248.15 304,247.48ZM298.79,248.74c-0.84,0.39 -0.75,0.8 -0.8,1.72s-1.4,1.79 -1.7,1.51 -0.76,0.1 -1.17,0.78 -1.77,1.3 -2.22,0.53 -0.9,-0.69 -1.8,-0.76a1.48,1.48 0,0 1,-1.43 -1.47c0,-0.71 0.3,-0.52 -1.06,-1.52s-1.13,-1.47 -0.75,-2a2.19,2.19 0,0 0,0.38 -2c-0.23,-1 0.27,-1.67 1.25,-1.62s0.65,-1.1 1.11,-1.5 0.65,0.2 1.7,-0.25 1,0.74 2.11,0.75 1.21,-0.88 1.88,-0.44 0,1.33 1.11,1.75 1.31,0.31 1.38,1.08 -0.45,1.7 0,2.11S299.58,248.34 298.74,248.74Z"/>
</vector>
```

The above code is the xml code of vector path in my kotlin project. "android pathData is very long  vector path"  warning is the issue here. How to fix this warning, can anybody help me to fix this issue. I am having this same warning in another 22 files  also in the layout resource files in my existing kotlin project

Comment: You can use Avocado: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem in my android project, but had about 10k characters.
Very big image for splash screen => [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqZIr.jpg)
As I can suggest, you have to try to reduce some elements in your xml file in the vector path. (These elements are small fragments of your image: when you'll delete some of them - vector will be lower, but image lose some details.

P.S: Perhaps this article https://medium.com/@claucookie/very-long-vector-path-issues-and-where-to-find-them-6db0f801503c will help you somehow :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to compromise the quality of your image, the only solution is to break the long path into several smaller ones, each containing at most 800 characters. This can be done using a graphical editor like Inkscape, for example, to split the object into multiple elements and import the resulting SVG back to Android Studio.